# What type of port is this?

Tags: port, array

What type of port is this? It is on the back of an older (circa 2006) EMC Array.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is an [HSSDC (High Speed Serial Data Connection) port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel_electrical_interface#8-pin_.22HSSDC.22_cable_connector_.28High_Speed_Serial_Data_Connection.29). It is used for Copper Fiber Channel connections.